# Get max value from varchar column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, max

I need to get max value from a column with varchar type. The value not too complicated, just simple values like `CAR 001` (without space), `CAR 002` (without space), `CAR 003` (without space).

I tried any answer from others question similar to this, but it always got an error in my SQL syntax, and the last one I tried is

```
SELECT MAX(CONVERT(`code`, UNSIGNED)) AS MAX FROM `account`
```

, but what I got is 0. The true one must be 3 from the case. Please help me, sorry for the bad English anyway.

Comment: Is the no of digits `001` fixed or it can vary?

Comment: it will be fixed, just assume it as auto increment value. till the max 999

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to isolate the number portion:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, ' ', -1) = (SELECT MAX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, ' ', -1))
                                       FROM yourTable);
```

Assuming only one record has the max ID, we could more simply use a `LIMIT` query:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, ' ', -1) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select max(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, ' ', -1)) from TableName
```